# Using JOptionPane.showMessageDialog tell the user how many they got right and wrong

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

Follow the comments in the code below: add 8 more questions and answers and at the end tell the user how many right and wrong they got for a score.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Quiz
{
       public static void main(String[] args)

       {
              String[] questions = 
                       {"How many players on a basketball team?\nA. 5 B. 6 C. 7",
                                      "How many points for a basket?\nA. 1 B. 2 C. 3",
                        "How many points for a free throw?\nA. 1 B.     2 C. 3"};
              //Add 8 more questions and answers
              char[] answers = {'A', 'B','A' };
              char ans = ' ';
              int x, correct = 0;
              String entry;
              boolean isGood;
              for(x = 0; x < questions.length; ++x)
              {
                         isGood = false;
                         int firstError = 0;
                         while(!isGood)
                         {
                                isGood = true;
                                entry = JOptionPane.showInputDialog
           (null,questions[x]);
                                ans = entry.charAt(0);
                                if(ans != 'A' && ans != 'B' && ans != 'C')
                                {
                                       isGood = false;
                                       if(firstError == 0)
                                       {
            questions[x] = questions[x] +
            "\nYour answer must be A, B or C.";
                                                firstError = 1;
                                        }
                                }
                           }
                           if(ans == answers[x])
                           {
                                   ++correct;
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
             "Correct!");
                            }
                            else
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The correct answer is " + answers[x]);
                    }
                    // Using JOptionPane.showMessageDialog tell the user how many they got right and wrong
             }
}
```

Comment: So, you have been giving some code and have been asked to modify it, yet, instead of making some effort, you've posted it here, without even asking a question? This is not how SO is suppose to work - your effort will be reward.  Where - specifically are you stuck? What have you tired and how did it not work for you?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure what you've been told about this site, but it's not a "we will do your homework site". It's a site made for professional (and enthusiast) programmers to help each other with problems. But we are also willing to help students (and beginners in general) if they show some effort in trying to solve the problems themselves first. So give it a shot and come back if there is something specific that got you stuck and explain to us what that is. Good luck and welcome to the site.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an updated version of your code:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Quiz
{
       public static void main(String[] args)

       {
              String[] questions = 
                       {"How many players on a basketball team?\nA. 5 B. 6 C. 7",
                        "How many points for a basket?         \nA. 1 B. 2 C. 3",
                        "How many points for a free throw?     \nA. 1 B. 2 C. 3",
                        "Question 4?                           \nA. 1 B. 2 C. 3",
                        "Question 5?                           \nA. 1 B. 2 C. 3",
                        "Question 6?                           \nA. 1 B. 2 C. 3",
                        "Question 7?                           \nA. 1 B. 2 C. 3",
                        "Question 8?                           \nA. 1 B. 2 C. 3",
                        "Question 9?                           \nA. 1 B. 2 C. 3",
                        "Question 10?                          \nA. 1 B. 2 C. 3",
                        "Question 11?                          \nA. 1 B. 2 C. 3"};
              //Add 8 more questions and answers
              char[] answers = {'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'B'};
              char ans = ' ';
              int x, correct = 0;
              String entry;
              boolean isGood;
              for(x = 0; x < questions.length; ++x)
              {
                         isGood = false;
                         int firstError = 0;
                         while(!isGood)
                         {
                                isGood = true;
                                entry = JOptionPane.showInputDialog (null,questions[x]);
                                ans = entry.charAt(0);
                                if(ans != 'A' && ans != 'B' && ans != 'C')
                                {
                                       isGood = false;
                                       if(firstError == 0)
                                       {
                                           questions[x] = questions[x] + "\nYour answer must be A, B or C.";
                                           firstError = 1;
                                        }
                                }
                           }
                           if(ans == answers[x])
                           {
                                ++correct;
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct!");
                            }
                            else
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The correct answer is " + answers[x]);
                    }
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You got " + correct + " correct answers and " + (answers.length-correct) + " wrong answers.");
             }
}
```

You'll need to modify your questions' text yourself :).